# "ExistenceError" in simple AppEngine + Google Cloud Storage application

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a simple AppEngine handler as follows:

```
class TestGS(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

        file_name = '/gs/ds_stats/testfile'
        files.gs.create(file_name, mime_type='text/html')        

        with files.open(file_name, 'a') as file_handle:

            file_handle.write("foo")

        files.finalize(file_name)
```

However, when I call this handler, I get `ExistenceError: ApplicationError: 105` at the line `with files.open(...`.

This seems like a super simple scenario, and there's no indication at all as to why this is failing (especially since the `files.gs.create` right above it seems to have succeeded, though, is there any way to verify this?).

Looking through the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/files/file.py#177), I see the following problems can cause this error:

```
  if (e.application_error in
      [file_service_pb.FileServiceErrors.EXISTENCE_ERROR,
       file_service_pb.FileServiceErrors.EXISTENCE_ERROR_METADATA_NOT_FOUND,
       file_service_pb.FileServiceErrors.EXISTENCE_ERROR_METADATA_FOUND,
       file_service_pb.FileServiceErrors.EXISTENCE_ERROR_SHARDING_MISMATCH,
       file_service_pb.FileServiceErrors.EXISTENCE_ERROR_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND,
       file_service_pb.FileServiceErrors.EXISTENCE_ERROR_BUCKET_NOT_FOUND,
       ]):
    raise ExistenceError()
```

That's a pretty large range of issues... Of course it doesn't tell me which one! And again, strange that the 'create' seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a lack of clarity in the documentation. `files.gs.create` returns a special 'writeable file path' which you need to feed in to `open` and `finalize`. A correct example looks like this:

```
class TestGS(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

        file_name = '/gs/ds_stats/testfile'
        writable_file_name = files.gs.create(file_name, mime_type='text/html')        

        with files.open(writable_file_name, 'a') as file_handle:

            file_handle.write("foo")

        files.finalize(writable_file_name)
```